# Python 3 Группировка списка с одинаковыми элементами

Tags: python

Например, есть вложенный список такого вида:

```
# имя, гендер, возраст
nlist = [
['Oleg', 1, 20],
['Aleksandr', 1, 19],
['Masha', 0, 22],
['Sasha', 0, 27],
['Masha', 0, 39],
['Masha', 0, 23],
]
```

Нужно посчитать возраст для элементов, у которых одинаковые имена и пол. На выходе получиться должно примерно следующее:

```
nlist = [
['Oleg', 1, 20],
['Aleksandr', 1, 19],
['Masha', 0, 84], #22 + 39 + 23
['Sasha', 0, 27],
]
```

Имеется ли какое-то универсальное решение для подобных задач?

Comment: Groupby с соответствующим ключом. П.С. Возраст Маш как-то не вдохновляет. Может, среднее взять?

Comment: А какое-нибудь своё хотя бы узкое решение разместите.

Comment: не бывает "частично одинаковых" элементов. они либо одинаковые, либо нет. у вас есть _одинаковые_ элементы списка списков. для табличных задач используйте pandas.

Comment: Да я знаю что не бывает "частично одинаковых", а бывают схожие, простите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение с помощью модуля itertools. Не скажу, что выглядит универсальным из-за обилия индексов:

```
from itertools import groupby
grouped = [[*g[0], sum(x[2] for x in list(g[1]))]
           for g in groupby(sorted(nlist), key=lambda x: (x[:2]))]
print(grouped)
```

> [['Aleksandr', 1, 19], ['Masha', 0, 84], ['Oleg', 1, 20], ['Sasha', 0, 27]]

вот решение с помощью pandas, которое, на мой взгляд, является более универсальным:

```
import pandas as pd
res = pd.DataFrame(nlist).groupby([0,1], as_index=False)[2].sum().values.tolist()
print(res)
```

> [['Aleksandr', 1, 19], ['Masha', 0, 84], ['Oleg', 1, 20], ['Sasha', 0, 27]]

Comment: Большое спасибо за pandas! Не знал про него.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже самое решение через `groupby`, но с использованием `namedtuple`, чтобы избавиться от непонятных индексов:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

Person = namedtuple('Person', ['name','gender','age'])

nlist = [
['Oleg', 1, 20],
['Aleksandr', 1, 19],
['Masha', 0, 22],
['Sasha', 0, 27],
['Masha', 0, 39],
['Masha', 0, 23],
]

persons = [Person(*i) for i in nlist]
grouped = [Person(k.name, k.gender, sum(x.age for x in v))
           for k,v in groupby(sorted(persons), lambda x: Person(x.name, x.gender, 0))]
pprint(grouped)
```

Вывод:

```
[Person(name='Aleksandr', gender=1, age=19),
 Person(name='Masha', gender=0, age=84),
 Person(name='Oleg', gender=1, age=20),
 Person(name='Sasha', gender=0, age=27)]
```

Если уж не хочется делать классы, то можно использовать `namedtuple`, чтобы обращаться к данным не по непонятым индексам, а по понятным именам полей.